# event_data() zoom compatibility with toggle bar in plotly (R)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I need to reset the zoom area due to some not shown functionality within my app. However, due to updating the zoom area of the plot, the pan functionality of the toggle bar does not work as expected:

- After clicking the pan button, the range is reset to the original value.
- To select the pan function, the button has to be clicked twice.

Any ideas or am I using the `event_data()` function incorrectly?

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")

scatterOutput <- function(id) {
  plotly::plotlyOutput(NS(id, "scatter"))
}

scatterServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$scatter <- plotly::renderPlotly({

      fig <- plotly::plot_ly(
          data = cars,
          source = "plotscatter"
        ) |>
        plotly::add_trace(
          x = ~speed,
          y = ~dist,
          type = "scatter",
          mode = "markers"
        )

      zoom <- plotly::event_data(
          "plotly_relayout",
          source = "plotscatter"
      )

      if (!is.null(zoom)) {
        fig <- fig |>
          plotly::layout(
            xaxis = list(
              range = list(zoom$`xaxis.range[0]`, zoom$`xaxis.range[1]`)
            ),
            yaxis = list(
              range = list(zoom$`yaxis.range[0]`, zoom$`yaxis.range[1]`)
            )
          )
      }

      fig
    })
  })
}

scatterApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    scatterOutput("test")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    scatterServer("test")
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```